# Create text file in a given folder

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, file-handling

I am developing a windows 8 app using Microsoft visual studio 2013. I needed to store the user entered data in a text file. I have wrote the following code segment to create the file and its working. But the text file is created in C:\Users...... I want to create the text file in a given folder. How can I modify my code to create the file in a folder where I specify.

```
StorageFile sampleFile;
const string fileName = "Sample.txt";
```

Comment: by "Windows 8 app" do you mean the "Immersive"/"Metro"-type applications? Those applications are sandboxed and cannot write to any arbitrary directory in the filesystem. I suggest following this article: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can create a file in C temp folder

```
String folderPath = @"C:/temp";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(folderPath + "\\Samplee.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
```

Comment: `C/temp` != `C:/temp`

Comment: @leppie, Corrected it

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer. He wants to use the class   [StorageClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) for Windows Store apps.  StorageClass is for Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 apps.

Comment: FileStream is highlighted as an error in my program code. but i am using System.IO namespace.

Answer (score 1):

As told before, Universal apps are sandboxed which means you can't write a file in an arbitrary folder.

You should take a look at the [File access sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597) on how to do it.

Also, you should take a look at the [ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx) which gives you a lot of choices for saving user entered data. Is it temporary, do you want it to be synced, is it a setting? There sure is a property that suits your needs.

**edit:** from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx this is what you should do

```
var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
var localFolder = applicationData.localFolder;

// Write data to a file

function writeTimestamp() {
   localFolder.createFileAsync("dataFile.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
      .then(function (sampleFile) {
         var formatter = new Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter("longtime");
         var timestamp = formatter.format(new Date());

         return Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(sampleFile, timestamp);
      }).done(function () {      
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the directory where you want to save the file.

Try this

```
       string dirctory = @"D:\Folder Name"; //This is the location where you want to save the file

        if (!Directory.Exists(dirctory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dirctory);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dirctory, "Sample.txt"), "Text you want to Insert");
```

Comment: I have import System.IO namespace but Directory is underlined as an error.